# How to write code for adaptor to get ad from our user defined network in adwhirl

Tags: adwhirl

I implemented one interface in that it has to implement `requestAd` on success and failure, `onLeaveApplication`, `onPresentScreen` , `onReceiveAd`. I also extended the AdwhirlLayout class. I implemented only two methods in `Adaptor.java` class `requestAd` on success and failure only by these lines

```
public void requestAdSuccess() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adWhirlLayout.adWhirlManager.resetRollover();
    adWhirlLayout.nextView = adView;
    adWhirlLayout.handler.post(adWhirlLayout.viewRunnable);
    adWhirlLayout.rotateThreadedDelayed();
}

public void requestAdFail() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adView.setAdListener(null);
    adWhirlLayout.rollover();
}
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I refresh my ad every 15 seconds. I wrote this based on `GoogleAdAdaptor.java` code in adwhirl sample. What else do I have to add to the code in `onLeaveApplication()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read my response to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540355/how-to-use-adwhirl-with-an-unsupported-ad-company/7543368#7543368) for information about implementing custom events.

From the code you've posted here, AdWhirlLayout doesn't have a nextView so I don't think `adWhirlLayout.nextView = adView;` will work.  Also, I think you will want to post the view runnable like this:

```
adWhirlLayout.handler.post(new ViewAdRunnable(adWhirlLayout, adView));
```

As far as I know, you're not missing anything in onLeaveApplication, unless the specific ad network you're working with does something special on leave.