# How to use tapjoy through AdWhirl? 

Tags: android, adwhirl, tapjoy

How to use tapjoy through AdWhirl?

Answer (score 1):

AdWhirl doesn't support TapJoy directly, so you would have to modify the AdWhirl code yourself  and use a [Custom Event](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/wiki/CustomEvents).

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540355/how-to-use-adwhirl-with-an-unsupported-ad-company/7543368#7543368) for details on how to implement a custom event in AdWhirl.